# Html form post Selection Drop-down php not posting to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

The issue seems easy enough, but I just don't get it. I took a look at multiple answers one suggested this fix where I add a variable and the name of the input element I'm like alright one line easy, I set it up add the row to the database and It submits but the database is empty.

HTML CODE

```
<label>Type of Business please Select One </label>
<select name="businesstype">
  <option value="corp">Corporation</option>
  <option value="llc">LLC</option>
  <option value="solepro" >Sole Proprietorship</option>
</select>
```

PHP CODE

```
$corp = $_POST['businesstype'];
$llc = $_POST['businesstype'];
$solepro = $_POST['businesstype'];
// Other POST elements

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $db_username, $db_pass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO enrolled (fulllegalcompname, dba, businessaddress, email, website, storenum, storefax, businesstype) VALUES ('$fulllegalcompname', '$dba', '$businessaddress', '$email', '$website', '$storenum', '$storefax', '$businesstype');";
```

Comment: Where in your code do these: `$corp` `$llc` `$solepro` become this `$businesstype`?

Comment: you are really assigning `$_POST['businesstype']` to those three variables? remember: your select is just a single select, it only has one value.

Comment: In the options is what I was thinking, that must be wrong. This is just what I gathered from another question. Do I need to name them instead? originally I tried it with one single value it didn't work that way either this was my second attempted fix

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**$businesstype** variable stored wrong value. please check below answer.

```
<?php
$businesstype = $_POST['businesstype'];
// Other POST elements

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $db_username, $db_pass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO enrolled (fulllegalcompname, dba, businessaddress, email, website, storenum, storefax, businesstype) VALUES ('$fulllegalcompname', '$dba', '$businessaddress', '$email', '$website', '$storenum', '$storefax', '$businesstype');";
?>
```

Comment: Why someone would downvote the correct answer I don't know. This was correct, someone else shared the answer I used as two different values and I was confused on what to use as the var. Thank you!

Comment: @Bama Okay. Welcome. please marked as a fixed. if your question was solved